# asp.net mvc - need to store some data for the current request

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am writing a user authentication class. During the request there are a lot of references to the current user, so I would like to cache it in memory instead of calling the database ala singleton. I am thinking about using session and clearing it at the end of every request.

like:

```
 public static User Current() {
     if (Session["current-user"] == null) {
          Session["current-user"] = GetUserFromDB(); // example function, not real
     }
     return (User)Session["current-user"];
```

then in app_end request:

```
     Session.Clear();
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
HttpContext.Items["user"] = user;
```

You can reference the context items during the entire request and it will be cleaned up at the end of it.

Comment: In view this is ViewContext.HttpContext.Items

Answer (score 11):

Use the `HttpContext` class.  You can get to it either in the context of a controller of `HttpContext.Current`.

The `HttpContext.Items` collection is what you want to use.